# ReactJS giving me an undefined error even though I have already defined it

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to React JS and I am trying to make a simple pokedex using React JS and Redux, however, for some reason I do not know, when I run my code, I get this error.

[image]

Here is my code for React

```
import React from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import _ from "lodash";
import {GetPokemonList} from "../actions/pokemonActions";


const PokemonList = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const pokemonList = useSelector(state => state.PokemonList);
    React.useEffect( () => {
        FetchData(1)
    });

    const FetchData = (page = 1) => {
        dispatch(GetPokemonList(page))
    }

    const ShowData = () => {
        if(!_.isEmpty(pokemonList.data)) {
            return <p>have data</p>
            }

        if (pokemonList.loading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>
            }

        if(pokemonList.errorMsg !== "") {
            return <p>{pokemonList.errorMsg}</p>
            }
        
        return <p>Unable to get data.</p>
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            {ShowData()}
        </div>
    )
};

export default PokemonList
```

Here is my code for my pokemonListReducer

```
const DefaultState = {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    errorMsg: ""
};

const PokemonListReducer = (state = DefaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "POKEMON_LIST_LOADING":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                errorMsg: ""
            };

        case "POKEMON_LIST_FAIL":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                errorMsg: "Unable to fetch pokemon",
                data: action.payload
            };

        case "POKEMON_LIST_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                errorMsg: "",
                data: action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state; 
    }
};
```

Here is my code for Store

```
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {composeWithDevTools} from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import RootReducer from "./reducers/RootReducer";  

const Store = createStore(RootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

export default Store

What I do not understand is why it says "tyring to property 'data' of undefined" when I have already set "pokemonList" as a const... so it should have a value right? Please help me smart people of the world.

Comment: your `useEffect` don't have any **dependencies**, thus it runs non-stop. is it intentional? If not, then add **empty array** to allow it **run once** upon rendered, `useEffect(() => FetchData(1), [])` or **run** it everytime `page` changes, `useEffect(() => FetchData(1), [page])`

Comment: can you show your `pokemonList` `reducer` code in your question please. You might have setup your `redux` incorrectly

Comment: @lala I added my code for my pokemonListReducer

I hope you can help me. Thanks for replying btw.

Comment: can you please provide your redux  store

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I added my code for store. I am following a tutorial on YouTube by Let'sCode

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbAENvrGbDo&t=534s

Comment: Did you have a look at redux devtools, your error means that you are trying to get a property off an undefined `undefined.someProp` that means that `state.PokemonList` is undefined. I'm sure if you have a look at redux devtools you'll find the problem quickly.